# Histogram blurring in Image Processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, smoothing

I have done image blurring using Gaussian Blur in opencv (smoothing). I came across in search in Google about histogram blurring. Now my question here is, do I apply blurring to the histogram or to the image and than reconstruct the histogram.

What I feel is that I apply to the image and than make the histogram because applying blurring to the histogram does not change any parameters and context about the image. Well I am not sure that is my reason but it will be really grateful if I can get some advice on this.

Comment: Sounds like [the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. What do you *really* want to do?

Comment: Actually, I just want to get ideas on it nothing else. I did image blurring project and i was just wondering what histogram smoothing would do.

Comment: I see - and as far as I'm aware, histogram blurring is used as part of a larger process, like adaptive contrast enhancement. For example [see page 3 of this paper](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~barner/courses/eleg675/papers/Enhancement%20in%20the%20Spatial%20Domain/Adaptive%20Image%20Contrast%20Enhancement.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

There is actually nothing called *Histogram blurring*. What you might be referring to is [Histogram Equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) or [Adaptive Histogram Equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization). There are many other related techniques if you read up on various papers referenced in the links.

The basic idea is - you apply a 1D transformation on the histogram and then transfer that histogram back onto the original image; thereby applying all changes on the contrast onto the original image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There most certainly is such a thing as histogram blurring. It appears to be the operation at the heart of the Clarify filter in MS Photos. It is distinctly different from HE/AHE. I don’t know where to get one though.

Comment: I have been working on image processing algorithms for a decade but I have not come across this term before. Could you give me a reference for the "Clarify" filter? I couldn't find it on my MS Photos app. Cheers!

Comment: Correction, "Clarity" not "Clarify". Using Microsoft Photos 2019.19071.17920.0, "
Edit & Create"  menu -> "Edit" -> "Adjustment" -> First slider on the sidebar. Screen shot: https://imgur.com/a/LZF92fQ. Also see section II.C here: https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~barner/courses/eleg675/papers/Enhancement%20in%20the%20Spatial%20Domain/Adaptive%20Image%20Contrast%20Enhancement.pdf

Comment: My answer is still valid. The paper you have linked to is for using Histogram Equalization in a specific context.