# Are there methods for histogram bluring in image processing?

Tags: image, image-processing, fpga

I'm looking for methods for **histogram blurring** in image processing. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533508/histogram-blurring-in-image-processing) old thread but the answers there does not solve my case. 
One answer there suggest that

> There is actually nothing called Histogram blurring.

so Is there any way for histogram blurring in image processing?

**[edit1] some more info**

- image size is 3880x2592.
- I want to blur with gaussian blur with radius about 15-20 (*pixels?).
- I am using 256×16bit 8ea(*?) single ports memories.
- I want to imlement this on FPGA

Answer (score 0):

if by blur you mean smooth (removing high frequencies) then you can use any smooth filter or algorithm (most of them are based on FIR low pass filters)

if your question is what to smooth then the answer is same as in the question you linked it depends on what you need:

- if you need smoothed histogram for some computation then smooth histogram directly and leave image be as is
- if you need the image colors to be smoothed then smooth image and recompute histogram

sometimes is hard to smooth image to get smoothed histogram

- (due to slow bleeding of colors or by too big data loss)

In that case you can smooth the histogram (remembering the original) then compute the area change for each color and statistically recolor whole image (it is not an easy task).

1. Pick (random) pixel of color `a` which area needs to be decreased and recolor it to closest color `b` thats area needs to be increased
2. update area of booth colors
3. loop until areas are matching ...

Comment: Thanks I mean that like gaussian smooth of Gimp the radius value 100.

Comment: First of all, I don't think color. Thus time just think gray.

Comment: @ddol gray is also color each intensity is single color

Comment: Yep  I know,  also I want to know is this can be possible methods or not.

Comment: @ddol look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur just create convolution weights matrix (2D for image and 1D for histogram)  by the equation of gaussian filter (centered on center of matrix) and do a convolution with image or histogram. matrix size in pixels is the diameter of blur. without further info (like what you need to smooth image/histogram/both? what platform,language...) is hard to answer better then this. btw are you using auto-translation the text is very hard to read/understand ?

Comment: @ddol have edited your post added marks (*...?)  what is not clear to me so read edit/repair. what is the purpose of the memories?  are you doing this on some MCU computer like Atmel,Pic,...? how much RAM memory you have at disposal  what is the desired output? how much bit per pixel/color? if 8bit grayscale then your image needs 9.5MB so there is no way to fit it directly in 512B memory!!!

Comment: oh. The purpose is making a FPGA. so that was mean. Sorry for make you read hard.

Comment: @ddol so specify more: 1. which FPGA chip, 2. where is the source Image? (camera,SD card,ROM,...?)  3. a block diagram of your board/device would be a good idea to include (what is connected with what ...) 4. decide if you need to blur image,histogram or both 5. where do you need the result stored and in what form? (encoding,resolution,...)  6. what is the target fps? 7. how many gates/resources do you have left for this task?

Comment: The only specification which is memory 256x16 8ea. Nothing else. The memories are all of seperated and single port memoies.

Comment: @ddol and the rest of the questions? btw memory is inside FPGA or external IO and how big (how many these 512B memories you have) ... right now it is highly unclear what exactly you need to achieve ...

Comment: The memories are in FPGA. Also total number of memories are 8. 512(W)x16bits 8 ea. it is already I wrote before.